# How to process data from AWS SQS?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I have a problem with understanding of working SQS from AWS in NodeJS. I'm creating a simple endpoint which receive data sended to my server and add to SQS queue:

```
export const receiveMessageFromSDK = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const payload = req.body;

    try {
        await sqs.sendMessage({
            QueueUrl: process.env.SQS_QUEUE_URL,
            MessageBody: payload 
        }).promise();
    } catch (error) {
        //something else
    }
}
```

and ok, it working and `MessageBody` is adding to my SQS queue. And right now I have a problem with processing of the data from this queue... How to do this?

In Google Cloud I'm creating simple request queue with sending (in body payload) also url of endpoint which should process data from queue, then gcloud send to this endpoint this body and my server starting business logic on this data. But how to do this in SQS? How to receive data from this queue and start processing data on my side?

I'm thinking about `QueueUrl` param but in docs is written that this value should be an url from aws console like `https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com...` so I have no idea how to process this data from queue on my side.

So..., can anybody help me?

Thanks, in advice for any help!

Comment: "have a problem" is not clear. What problem exactly? Your question is not detailed. Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin thanks for interesting this topic, I have a problem with receiving any message from the queue, I know that i need to create function `sqs.receiveMessage()` but when this function is calling and receiving data from sqs? Should I launch this function on cron or AWS can eq. send request on providing from me endpoint with this data etc., how to consume this data from queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I call launch this function on cron or AWS can eq. send request on providing from me endpoint with this data etc

SQS is for **pulling data**, which means that you have to have a `cron` job working (or any equivalent system in your app) that iteratively pulls your queue for messages using  `receiveMessage`, , e.g. every 10 seconds.

If you want push type messaging system, then you have to use **SNS** instead of SQS. SNS can [push messages to your HTTP/HTTPS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html) endpoint automatically if your application exposes any such endpoint for the messages.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I have one more question, SQS vs SNS, if I receive from the external sources data eq. 10x/minute and I want to queueing this data, should I use SNS or SQS with cron running eq. in every 15-20 seconds?

Comment: @BokuNoHeeeero SNS is not for queuing. SQS is a queuing service thus it would be preferred in that case.

Comment: I'm preety disappointed with the possibilities of the SQS, the running cron or worker which launch receiveMessage is a not too good way in many cases cause I want to get from data from queue instantly when previous data has been processed..., weird, I'm back to gcloud

Comment: @BokuNoHeeeero You can use long polling and poll constantly - there is no issue. It's not an AWS flaw, it's a flaw in your understanding of the AWS ecosystem.

Comment: @BokuNoHeeeero As I wrote, you can use SNS. But away, not sure why did you un-accepted my answer. The answer is correct whether you like it or not unfortunately.